# ¿problema con routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo dos modelos, `Tarea` y `Comentario`, y la relación es de uno a muchos. Este seria el código para mi enrutador:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tareas do
    resources :comentarios
  end
  root to:'tareas#index' 
  #put 'tareas/finalizar'
  match 'tareas/finalizar/:id', to:'tareas#finalizar',via: :get
  get 'tareas/create'
  get 'tareas/new'

  get 'tareas/show'

  get 'tareas/edit'

  get 'tareas/update'

  get 'tareas/destroy'


end
```

cuando llamo a la función `finalizar tarea` debería ejecutarme el controlador tareas con el método finalizar, pero al parecer no me reconoce este método.[image: Error no reconoce el metodo]

Código de mi controlador

```
class TareasController < ApplicationController
      def index        @tareas=Tarea.select("id,titulo,descripcion").where(:activo=>true).order("id DESC")
      end

      def new
        @tarea=Tarea.new()
      end

      def create
        @tarea=Tarea.new(tarea_params)
        @tarea.activo=true
      if @tarea.save()
        redirect_to tareas_path,:notice=>"La tarea se guardo correctamente"
      else
        render "new"
      end
    end

      def show
        @tarea=buscar_id
      end
    private
     def buscar_id
    Tarea.find(params[:id])

      end
        def edit
        @tarea=Tarea.find(params[:id])
        @titulo=@tarea.titulo
        @descripcion=@tarea.descripcion
        @prioridad=@tarea.prioridad
        puts "tarea #{@tarea.titulo} descripcion #{@tarea.descripcion}"
        end

      def update
        @titulo=params[:tarea]["titulo"]
        @descripcion=params[:tarea]["descripcion"]
        @prioridad=params[:tarea]["prioridad"]
        @tarea=Tarea.find(params[:id])
        @tarea.titulo=@titulo
        @tarea.descripcion=@descripcion
        @tarea.prioridad=@prioridad
        if @tarea.save()
          redirect_to tareas_path,:notice=>" La tarea a sido modificado exitosamente"

        else
    render "edit"      
        end


      end

      def destroy
        @tarea=buscar_id
        if @tarea.destroy()
          redirect_to tareas_path,:notice=>"la Tarea a sido eliminado correctamente"

        else
          redirect_to tareas_path,:notice=>"la tarea no ha sido elminada"

        end
      end
      private 
      def tarea_params
        params.require(:tarea).permit(:titulo,:descripcion,:prioridad)
      end


        def finalizar
         @tarea=Tarea.find(params[:id])
         @tarea.activo=false
          if @tarea.update()
             redirect_to tareas_path,:notice=>"la tarea a finalizado"
          else
           redirect_to tareas_path,:notice=>"la tarea NO  a finalizado"
          end
          end
    end
```

Comment: ¿Y cual es el código de tu controlador? cuando hagas una pregunta procura agregar toda la información que veas esté relacionada con ésta y no esperar que se te vaya pidiendo poco a poco. Ya llevas un tiempo en la página y deberías saber como hacer una pregunta o al menos ponerle un poco más de esfuerzo al realizarla. Saludos

Comment: El mensaje de error que muestras, dice que no se pudo encontrar el método "finalizar" en tu controlador de Tareas. ¿Estás seguro que el método *finalizar* existe? ¿Está bien escrito? ¿No lo declaraste por error como un método privado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando defines "Private" en un controlador, todos los métodos que vienen detrás de esa declaración serán privados, salvo que vuelvas a declarar otra visibilidad. Tal como te sugiere Gerry deberías dejar todos los métodos privados o protegidos para el final para organizar mejor tu código y evitar este problema.

Además del problema en tu controlador también tienes errores en tu archivo de rutas:
En primer lugar cuanto pones

```
resources :tareas
```

ya estás creando todas tus rutas REST (index, new, create, show, edit, update, destroy). Más abajo vuelves a crear las mismas acciones. Sin embargo no lo estás haciendo bien. Si quisieras por ejemplo crear la ruta para la acción "show", necesitarás pasar el ID en la ruta (después lo estás usando en el controlador). Por lo tanto la manera correcta de crear esa ruta "manualmente" sería:

```
get "tareas/:id", to "tareas#show"
```

Por otro lado cuidado que hay acciones que no deberían ser GET. Es muy mala práctica modificar un recurso a partir de una llamada GET. Para crearlos deberías usar POST, para modificarlos PUT o PATCH y para destruirlos DELETE. GET debería ser siempre seguro e indempotente y vale la pena que leas un poco más sobre esto.

Pero repito, todas esas rutas que usas en tu controlador las creas con el "resources :tareas". Por lo tanto todo tu archivo de rutas podría reducirse a:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :tareas do
    member do
      put "finalizar"
    end
    resources :comentarios
  end
end
```

Notas: La ruta que se crea para finalizar es levemente distinta a la que creas tu pero es más estandar. En vez de ser "tareas/finalizar/:id" la ruta será "tareas/:id/finalizar". Por otro lado fíjate que "finalizar" también lo puse como PUT y no GET. Por lo tanto deberías especificar este método cuando crees tus links o redireccionamientos. Ejemplo en una vista:

```
<%= link_to "Finalizar", finalizar_tareas_path(@tarea), method: :put %>
```

Answer (score 1):

La acción `finalizar` está después de `private`, esto quiere decir que no es un método público y, por ende, no se encuentra al intentar ejecutarlo.

Simplemente mueve ese método (`finalizar`) **antes** de la declaración de métodos privados (i.e. antes de `private`).

Así se debería ver tu controlador:

```
class TareasController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @tareas = Tarea.select("id,titulo,descripcion").where(:activo=>true).order("id DESC")
  end

  def new
    @tarea = Tarea.new
  end

  def create
    @tarea = Tarea.new(tarea_params)
    @tarea.activo = true

    if @tarea.save
      redirect_to tareas_path, :notice => "La tarea se guardo correctamente"
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def show
    @tarea = buscar_id
  end

  def buscar_id
    Tarea.find(params[:id])
  end

  def edit
    @tarea = Tarea.find(params[:id])
    @titulo = @tarea.titulo
    @descripcion = @tarea.descripcion
    @prioridad = @tarea.prioridad
    puts "tarea #{@tarea.titulo} descripcion #{@tarea.descripcion}"
  end

  def update
    @titulo = params[:tarea]["titulo"]
    @descripcion = params[:tarea]["descripcion"]
    @prioridad = params[:tarea]["prioridad"]
    @tarea = Tarea.find(params[:id])
    @tarea.titulo = @titulo
    @tarea.descripcion = @descripcion
    @tarea.prioridad = @prioridad

    if @tarea.save
      redirect_to tareas_path, :notice => "La tarea a sido modificado exitosamente"
    else
      render "edit"      
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @tarea = buscar_id
    if @tarea.destroy
      redirect_to tareas_path, :notice=> "la Tarea a sido eliminado correctamente"
    else
      redirect_to tareas_path, :notice=> "la tarea no ha sido eliminada"
    end
  end

  def finalizar
    @tarea = Tarea.find(params[:id])
    @tarea.activo = false

    if @tarea.update
      redirect_to tareas_path, :notice => "la tarea a finalizado"
    else
      redirect_to tareas_path, :notice => "la tarea NO  a finalizado"
    end
  end  

  private 
  def tarea_params
    params.require(:tarea).permit(:titulo, :descripcion, :prioridad)
  end
end
```

Notarás que también eliminé la primer declaración `private` (justo antes de `buscar_id`) ya que es innecesaria pues la vuelves a incluir más abajo. Si quieres que el método `buscar_id` sea privado entonces mueve ese método hacia el final, después de `private`.

Aunque es posible que agregues métodos privados antes de métodos públicos (utilizando `private` y `public`) no es recomendado pues tu código tiende a ser menos ordenado y más difícil de actualizar/depurar; por lo tanto lo mejor es declarar todos los métodos públicos primero y después todos los privados.